# Is there a Biblical precedent for the Petrine privilege?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, marriage, canon-law

Is there a Biblical precedent for the [Petrine privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrine_privilege)?

The Petrine privilege per the Code of Canon Law being

> Code of Canon Law **[Can.  1142](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P44.HTM)** For a just cause, the Roman
>   Pontiff can dissolve a non-consummated marriage between baptized
>   persons or between a baptized party and a non-baptized party at the
>   request of both parties or of one of them, even if the other party is
>   unwilling.

Comment: Good question. And +1 for asking if there is a Biblical precedent, as opposed to assuming there is one with a question like "What is the Biblical precedent...?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cf. **The Petrine Privilege** | [Marriage, Divorce and The Pauline Privilege, by Randal D. Noller | Catholic Culture](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?id=7272&repos=1&subrepos=0&searchid=1440088)

> The Pauline Privilege does not apply when a Christian has married a
>   non-Christian. In those cases, a natural marriage exists and can be
>   dissolved for a just cause, but by what is called the Petrine
>   Privilege rather than by the Pauline Privilege. The Petrine Privilege
>   is so-named because it is reserved to the Holy See, so only Rome can
>   grant the Petrine Privilege. The Petrine Privilege is rarely approved.
>   It is the dissolution of a valid, but non-sacramental, natural bond of
>   marriage by the Holy See in certain, specified cases. The
>   determination is based on case-specific facts and circumstances, and
>   is not often used.
>
> **A biblical precedent for the Petrine Privilege, where some of the
>   faithful marry unbelievers and then are permitted to divorce them, is
>   found in the book of Ezra where the Jews put away their foreign
>   (pagan) wives.**
>
> … We have broken faith with our God and have married foreign women from
>   the people of the land…Therefore let us make a covenant with our God
>   to put away all these wives and their children, according to the
>   counsel of my lord…
>
> … separate yourselves from the peoples of the land and from the foreign
>   wives. [cf. [Ezra 10]](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=RSVCE&search=Ezra%2010)

The privilege is understood when Israel is seen as the type of the Church.

Comment: This must assume that they never consummated their marriages in Ezra right? I would never have thought that when reading it...

Comment: @curiousdannii My understanding is that even if they did, that marriage can be dissolved. he Roman Pontiff can dissolve a non-consummated marriage between baptized persons **OR** between a baptized party and a non-baptized party ... non-consummation only refers to baptized persons.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Petrine privilege and all the customs around it grew out of the practical administration of the sacraments over time.  There is nothing in the scripture recognized as the canonized New Testament that speaks directly to any of this.  If anything all of this can be said to have grown out of Jesus admonition not to divorce - Matthew 19:1-12.

Comment: I think this is probably the right answer, but limiting it to the New Testament isn't sufficient. The Catholic church also uses the Old Testament and the Apocrypha as scripture canon. Is there any Biblical precedent in these works?